# Resource Hacker выводит иероглифы

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering, pe

Я пытаюсь разобрать один exe файл, когда я открываю его в Resource Hacker FX он выводит иероглифы.

[image: Иероглифы]

Могу ли я увидеть такой вывод? (для примера вывод от другого exe) или что я могу предпринять чтоб увидеть эту информацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Resource Hacker под рукой нет, я бы меню "вид" потыкал (и другие меню), может там что-то есть. Или экспортировал ресурс, открыл отдельным hex-редактором.

Comment: а что там - это нужно автора программы спросить - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/rcdata-resource - `Defines a raw data resource for an application. Raw data resources permit the inclusion of binary data directly in the executable file.` - то есть, там может быть все, что угодно. абсолютно.